# Copying exact amount of files via scp

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm copying pictures form my iphone via scp, where filenames looks like this `IMG_3134.JPG`. And let's say I'd like to copy files from `IMG_3094.JPG` to `IMG_3134.JPG`. Using special characters like `*` or `?` wont get me anywhere and simple bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1;
b=$2;
let b=b+1
while [ $a -lt $b ]; do
    scp IMG_$a.* user@192.168.1.2:/home/user/
    let a=a+1
done
```

requires to type a password every time when file is copied. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bash` [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) :

```
IMG_30{94..99}.JPG IMG_31{00..34}.JPG
```

to generate file names from `IMG_3094.JPG` to `IMG_3134.JPG`.

It actually has two expansions :

- `IMG_30{94..99}.JPG` will be expanded from `IMG_3094.JPG` to `IMG_3099.JPG`
- `IMG_31{00..34}.JPG` will be expanded from `IMG_3100.JPG` to
  `IMG_3134.JPG`

So your `scp` can be done with this one liner :

```
scp IMG_30{94..99}.JPG IMG_31{00..34}.JPG user@192.168.1.2:/home/user/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a `for` loop to collect the filenames into the `$files` variable, and the sequence of numbers between the two arguments provided as input parameters to your script, you could try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=""
a=$1
b=$2
for i in `seq $a $b`;
do
    files="$files IMG_${i}.JPG"
done

scp $files user@192.168.1.2:/home/user/
```